# Perverse sheaves with stable infinity categories

Tags: higher-algebra, perverse-sheaves

I hope this question is not too naive.

I have recently been trying to get familiar with the theory of stable $\infty$-categories. Lurie's Higher Algebra explains that they are a useful 'upgrade' of the derived category. My primary interactions with triangulated categories has been in the world of perverse sheaves.

This has led me to wonder: can one formulate the theory of perverse sheaves in the language of stable $\infty$-categories, rather than triangulated categories? And is this a useful thing to do?

I'm imagining the answer for the first part will be an easy 'yes' unless there is some technical complication that has gone way over my head, so I am more interested in the utility of such a thing. Would a modern person think of perverse sheaves using stable $\infty$-categories? I've tried searching variations of 'perverse sheaves and stable infty-categories' to no avail.

Comment: You might see applications in this paper, for instance : https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.05004 (see thm 1.6).

Comment: t-structures on stable $\infty$-categories are simply those on the underlying triangulated categories. One advantage of $\infty$-categories in this context is that they would satisfy descent that does not hold on the triangulated level. An example is the recent work of David Hansen and Peter Scholze on the construction of the perverse t-structure in the relative setting, available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.06766).